# how to connect mongo db composs into express.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i am running express.js inside electron and i am trying to connect mongodb composs to expressjs

when i start my express.js using electron i am getting error in mongodb
i have created the db in mongodb composs here is the error

[image: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6mxb.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6mxb.png)]

here is the code for express .js

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");

async function startExpressServer() {
  // Connect to MongoDB
  await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/pos", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB");

  const expressApp = express();
  expressApp.use(cors());

  expressApp.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello World from Express!");
  });

  return expressApp;
}

module.exports = { startExpressServer };
```

in main.js i have  this code which stats my express app

```
app.on("ready", async () => {
  // Start the Express server
  const expressApp = await startExpressServer();
  const port = 3001;
  expressApp.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
  });

  createMainWindow();
});
```

this code worked and ran the express app  before i added monogo db connetion

Comment: **Possible Solution :**  Go to task manager > services > check if MngoDB service is currently running or not. If not right click on it and start the service.

Comment: @debugger the status of mongo db is running in  services

Comment: Here  `const expressApp = await startExpressServer()` the error is saying startExpressServer is not a function.

Comment: @debugger i have updated my code and error now i have added  async function startExpressServer() and  tryed to connet mongodb inside of it but i got the error as in screen shot when i remove the code to connet my mongodb the express app is working

Comment: @debugger i think the issue is with envionmet variabele

Answer (score 1):

To suppress the warning make the `mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);`. and instead of `localhost` and `0.0.0.0`

```
 mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
 await mongoose.connect("mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/pos", {
    useNewUrlParser: true, // no need this in the new version
    useUnifiedTopology: true, // no need this in the new version
  });
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the first warning you can try this before the connect statement.

```
 mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
```